How to enable QR code tracking on Hololens2 using MRTK3?
I am a beginner and have been working with Unity 2022, Hololens 2, OpenXR, and MRTK3. For my project, I am trying to enable QR code tracking such that every time a QR code is detected by the Hololens, a sphere game object is rendered on top of this QR code. I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me through all the necessary steps.
I followed these resources to get started-

qr code tracking in unity
Microsoft's sample github repo
I was able to render the sphere when I made changes to the cloned repository on the OpenXR branch by adding a sphere game object to the QRCode Prefab and assigning scale and position to the sphere inside QRCode.cs. When I tried to replicate the same stuff by copying the scripts and prefabs from this repo to my new project that uses MRTK3 I started getting a bunch of namespace errors. I think this project uses an older MRTK version(2) and I don't know if that makes a difference. Most of the content I have found so far is related to MRTK2, which doesn't help much given the changes. I am attaching a screenshot for your reference.

Am I missing something here? I cannot figure what needs to be done.
Thanks in advance!

I had a similar issue not too long ago (though using Unity 2021), after trying a handful of different approaches, i found this blog https://localjoost.github.io/Upgrading-reading-and-positioning-QR-codes-with-HoloLens-2-to-Unity-2020-+-OpenXR-plugin/ which solved my issues. IIRC some of his code samples were also slightly deprecated, but easy to fix using Visual Studio replacement suggestions.

Would you be so kind to describe the solution you found from that blog in your answer here? That blog may disappear over time.

From the error messages you provided here, your project lacks the QR code NuGet package. Additionally, I recommend using the recommended version of Unity 2021.3 LTS for MR development.
Note if using Unity version 2020 or above with OpenXR plugin, please use the “openxr” branch of QRCode sample repro. For more details, refer to https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-QRCode-Sample?tab=readme-ov-file#openxr-sample.

Thank you for your response! I had already installed the Nuget package based on this link and got the error anyway. I had switched the branch to "openxr" before opening the project in unity but when I created a project from scratch and copied the scripts into the new project from the sample these errors came up(as shown in screenshot). I also followed this but wasn't able to place the hologram on top of the qr code.

please open a support ticket through aka.ms/HLDevSupport so we can do a deep diagnosis.
